# Customizing HTML <input> tag's camera functionality on iPhone and Android

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

I am developing a webapp specifically for smartphone which needs access to system camera. I know it can be accessed as follows:

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
```

The option above opens smartphone's camera and allows you to take picture in high resolution, which is great! However, I would like the change the user to be able to capture image once he/she taps on the camera preview that opens up after user selects to use camera. System camera automatically has tapping option set for focus. I know this is possible on Smartphone Apps (tested for both Android and iPhone). Is it possible to customize the system camera functionality in this case?

Or is there any other solution which can have a photo camera with high-resolution and on figure tap being the click for image capture?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to let users take a snapshot of themselves with the webcam, that's possible with capture=camera:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
```

Recording a video or audio is similar:

```
<input type="file" accept="video/*;capture=camcorder">
<input type="file" accept="audio/*;capture=microphone">
```

Check more at : [https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/12/imagecapture](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/)

Comment: Hi Daniel, I was looking to add a functionality on the camera that gets opened. The functionality that I want to add is letting user tap on the screen of camera preview to take a picture. I am aware of getUserMedia which uses the video camera, not the photo camera since resolution is important for my application.

Comment: This might more specific what you are looking for - https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/12/imagecapture